# Конструктор интерфейса netbeans

Tags: android, ide, netbeans

Установил netbeans 8.0.1, поставил плагин nbandroid. Интерфейс можно редактировать через xml. В netbeans нет графического редактора интерфейса, как в eclipse?

Comment: @yuri-87, ставьте идею

Comment: а ещё лучше android studio:)

Comment: @yuri-87, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.